# Controlling Source Image From Script

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am trying to make a health system where hearts display how much health you have. On each heart, I have an Image component. I am trying to control what source image the Image component uses from a script, but it is not letting me. I read the documentation for the Image component [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html) and it has no sprite property. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class HeartScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject heart1;
    public GameObject heart2;
    public GameObject heart3;
    public Sprite halfHeart;
    public Sprite fullHeart;
    public Sprite emptyHeart;
    private double playerHealth = 3;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(playerHealth == 2.5)
        {
            heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image = fullHeart;
            heart2.GetComponent<Image>().image = fullHeart;
            heart3.GetComponent<Image>().image = halfHeart;
        }
        else if(playerHealth == 2)
        {
            heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image = fullHeart;
            heart2.GetComponent<Image>().image = fullHeart;
            heart3.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
        }
        else if(playerHealth == 1.5)
        {
            heart3.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart2.GetComponent<Image>().image = halfHeart;
            heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image = fullHeart;
        }
        else if(playerHealth == 1)
        {
            heart3.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart2.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image = fullHeart;
        }
        else if(playerHealth == .5)
        {
            heart3.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart2.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image = halfHeart;
        }
        else if(playerHealth == 0)
        {
            heart3.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart2.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
            heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image = emptyHeart;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveHealth()
    {
        playerHealth = playerHealth - 0.5;
    }
}
```

How do I change the sprite the heart uses from a script?

Comment: I think you should try `heart1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite` instead of `heart1.GetComponent<Image>().image`

Comment: Did you mean to use UnityEngine.UI.Image, rather than UnityEngine.UIElements.Image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your script:

1. As @Safa mentioned that the Image has the property of sprit to change the sprite of the image.
2. You are using wrong namespace.
   Change

> using UnityEngine.UIElements

To

> using UnityEngine.UI

Also, I made some changes to the script for better performance. Reasign value to hear1, heart2, heart3 as I changed it form game object to Image.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HeartScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image heart1;
    public Image heart2;
    public Image heart3;
    public Sprite halfHeart;
    public Sprite fullHeart;
    public Sprite emptyHeart;
    private double playerHealth = 3;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerHealth == 2.5)
        {
            heart1.sprite = fullHeart;
            heart2.sprite = fullHeart;
            heart3.sprite = halfHeart;
        }
        else if (playerHealth == 2)
        {
            heart1.sprite = fullHeart;
            heart2.sprite = fullHeart;
            heart3.sprite = emptyHeart;
        }
        else if (playerHealth == 1.5)
        {
            heart3.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart2.sprite = halfHeart;
            heart1.sprite = fullHeart;
        }
        else if (playerHealth == 1)
        {
            heart3.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart2.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart1.sprite = fullHeart;
        }
        else if (playerHealth == .5)
        {
            heart3.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart2.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart1.sprite = halfHeart;
        }
        else if (playerHealth == 0)
        {
            heart3.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart2.sprite = emptyHeart;
            heart1.sprite = emptyHeart;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveHealth()
    {
        playerHealth = playerHealth - 0.5;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Huh, I don't know why I switched it from `using UnityEngine.UI;` to `using UnityEngine.UIElements;`. Must have been while trying to debug it. Thanks though, this code works great.

Comment: I am glad it helps.